# Why use OurDelta (alternative MySQL distribution)?

Tags: mysql

This is a question asked to people **who have used** OurDelta in production:

- Why did you choose OurDelta over the standard MySQL distribution?
- Pros/cons of OurDelta compared to the standard MySQL distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The killer app of the OurDelta distribution, for us at least, are the awesome index and table statistics that are exposed. However, our DBAs say that the distribution is made of win for many reasons; it makes better use of SSDs, better use of large RAM, etc, etc.